# How to hide/remove left side dock in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, gui, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Please refer screenshot, I installed "Dash to Panel" gnome extension so that my dash and top panel appear in single unit. But the left side default dock is still there. How can I remove the left side dock? Thanks.

[image: Desktop Screenshot]

Comment: If you right-click on them and then 'remove from favorites' they should disappear. However they will still be shown while running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable the extension "Ubuntu Dock" in tweak tools.

Probably, in tweak tools, that extension will appear not to be turned on. In that case, click twice on the toggle: once to turn it on and a second time to turn it of again. After that, the dock will be disabled.

Comment: This has no effect for me. Whether it's turned on or not, that obnoxious dock shows up.

Answer (score 3):

Open Ubuntu Software Center, click search sign at the right upper corner of the window and type in the search field "Gnome extensions dash to dock" phrase. You'll see the "Dash to Dock" Gnome shell extension.

[image]

Install the extension and configure it to hide Ubuntu Dock.

Answer (score 1):

If Ubuntu dock in tweak tool is disable and dock is still visible : open dconf editor (install dconf editor : Sudo apt install dconf-tools)
now navigate : org->gnome->shell->extensions->dash-to-dock 
find **dock-fixed** and change to **false**

Edit : if you have problem again navigate : org->gnome->shell->extensions->dash-to-dock find intelihide and change to false

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was one of the solutions [mentioned here](https://linuxhint.com/hide-dock-in-ubuntu/), which was to completely disable the "Ubuntu Dock" extension. Disabling it in the Gnome Tweak UI, or setting it to "auto-hide" in the main settings UI, had no effect for me, but running:

```
gnome-extensions disable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

finally made that horribly annoying dock disappear.